# Typescript node express controller. What type of return has to be?

Tags: typescript, express

What type return function in node express? I read that I can write **any** or **void**. In this case **void** is exactly **NOT**. Are there some suggestions? Now I see I can use like this `Promise<Response<any>>` and I should turn off this rule "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any" but I wouldn't like turn it off

```
                                                     //Here: Promise<Response<any>> 
export default async function registration(req: TreqBodyReg, res: Response) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const candidate = await ModelUser.findOne({ email }) as TreqBodyReg;
    if (candidate) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: `There is user with email ${email}` });
    }
    const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 7);
    const user = new ModelUser({ email, password: hashPassword });
    await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({ message: `The user by email ${email} was successfully registered` });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
    return res.status(400).json({ message: `registration error is ${err}` });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express doesn't expect any return value from the middleware/routing function, so `void` would be appropriate — `Promise<void>` in your case, since you're using an `async` function:

```typescript
export default async function registration(req: TreqBodyReg, res: Response): Promise<void> {
```

Some people like to use `return` combined with the last thing they did, as you have here:

```
return res.status(400).json({ message: `There is user with email ${email}` });
```

The [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) doesn't list any return value for `json`, so it probably results in `undefined` although many Express methods are "chainable" so it might return the `Response`. If so, you could separate the lines:

```
res.status(400).json({ message: `There is user with email ${email}` });
return;
```

Comment: *(As a matter of style, I've never cared for returning the result of a function call from an Express middleware handler. They aren't meant to return anything, so I use bare `return;` where I need to bail early. But I also try to avoid bailing early, by keeping my handlers short, relying on reusable helper functions.)*

Comment: I thought so before but I thought eslint would be cuss at me cuz I return nothing but it wouldn't. Problem solved, thnx

Comment: What about err? Leave any?

Comment: @HackerMF - Probably, since any value can be thrown in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Code was wrote this way

```
export default async function registration(req: TreqBodyReg, res: Response): Promise<Response<void>> {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const candidate = await ModelUser.findOne({ email }) as TreqBodyReg;
    if (candidate) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: `There is user with email ${email}` });
      return;
    }
    const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 7);
    const user = new ModelUser({ email, password: hashPassword });
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json({ message: `The user by email ${email} was successfully registered` });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
    res.status(400).json({ message: `registration error is ${err}` });
  }
};
```